# jQuery dynamic table searches

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a dynamic calculator for a table

And for this table I have:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar Pedido 00.00 $</button>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is , when user writes something in a input , the value searches for the price and multiplies it. And that sum gets added to the button.

So if I would write 2 in the #item1 , I would have 5 dollars in the Enviar Pedido.

What I did so far:

```
$('input#item1').keypress(function() {
  alert('a');
});
```

I'm really struggling and all I could find out is to use the keypress for any modification in the input. It doesn't seem right though to do this for all 8 inputs + I'm not sure how to search in the parent for the "Valor" value.

https://jsfiddle.net/a7u1y8bc/1/

```js
$('input#item1').keypress(function() {
  alert('a');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Item</th>
      <th scope="col">Valor</th>
      <th scope="col">Quantidade</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Batata Inglesa (500g)</td>
      <td>R$ 2,50</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="item1" name="item1" step="1" min="0" max="10"></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>Beterraba (500g)</td>
      <td>R$ 2,50</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="item2" name="item2" step="1" min="0" max="10"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Cenoura (500g)</td>
      <td>R$ 2,50</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="item3" name="item3" step="1" min="0" max="10"></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>Alface Crespa (1 un)</td>
      <td>R$ 2,50</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="item4" name="item4" step="1" min="0" max="10"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Alface Lisa (1 un)</td>
      <td>R$ 2,50</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="item5" name="item5" step="1" min="0" max="10"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Brócolis (1 maço)</td>
      <td>R$ 2,50</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="item6" name="item6" step="1" min="0" max="10"></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>Hortelã (1 maço)</td>
      <td>R$ 2,50</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="item7" name="item7" step="1" min="0" max="10"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Limão Cravo (500g)</td>
      <td>R$ 2,50</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="item8" name="item8" step="1" min="0" max="10"></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar Pedido 0.00</button>
```

Comment: I made a correction on the event. https://jsfiddle.net/a7u1y8bc/9/

Comment: @Roy how would I go about finding the value to the left of the input and multiplying it with val() of the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I've changed the event to be attached to `table input[type=number]`, which is *"Any number input within a table"*. If you need to be more specific than that, consider using a class on all the inputs instead.
- To get the `Valor <td>` element, you can do the following:

  ```
  $(this)              //The input being changed
      .closest("td")   //Its parent TD
      .prev();         //The previous sibling
  ```
- Once you have that, you can get the value of it using `.text()`. You'll have to remove the `R$` and replace the `,` with a `.` before attempting to parse it as a number.
- You'll have to do that for every input in the table, so I've wrapped that logic in an `.each()`.
- The result is formatted with two decimal places and a comma, using `.toFixed(2).replace('.',',');`

```js
var $numberInputs = $('table input[type=number]');
var $btn = $('button.btn.btn-primary');

$numberInputs.keyup(function() {
  var sum = getSumOfInputs().toFixed(2).replace('.',',');
  $btn.text("Enviar Pedido " + sum);
});

function getSumOfInputs() {
  var result = 0.00;
  $numberInputs.each(function() {
    var $td = $(this).closest("td").prev();
    var valor = parseFloat($td.text().replace('R$ ', '').replace(',', '.'));
    var qty = parseInt($(this).val() || 0);
    result += (valor * qty);
  });

  return result;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Item</th>
      <th scope="col">Valor</th>
      <th scope="col">Quantidade</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Batata Inglesa (500g)</td>
      <td>R$ 2,50</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="item1" name="item1" step="1" min="0" max="10"></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>Beterraba (500g)</td>
      <td>R$ 2,50</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="item2" name="item2" step="1" min="0" max="10"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Cenoura (500g)</td>
      <td>R$ 2,50</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="item3" name="item3" step="1" min="0" max="10"></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>Alface Crespa (1 un)</td>
      <td>R$ 2,50</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="item4" name="item4" step="1" min="0" max="10"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Alface Lisa (1 un)</td>
      <td>R$ 2,50</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="item5" name="item5" step="1" min="0" max="10"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Brócolis (1 maço)</td>
      <td>R$ 2,50</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="item6" name="item6" step="1" min="0" max="10"></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>Hortelã (1 maço)</td>
      <td>R$ 2,50</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="item7" name="item7" step="1" min="0" max="10"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Limão Cravo (500g)</td>
      <td>R$ 2,50</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="item8" name="item8" step="1" min="0" max="10"></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar Pedido 0.00</button>
```

Comment: the 'result' var will contain the value of the last input modified, not all of them summed up.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value to the left of the input using jQuery `parent()` and `prev()`. Then use `replace()` to get the desired result, so something like...

```
    $('input#item1').keypress(function() {
        const price = $(this).parent().prev().text();
    const v = $(this).val();
    const d = parseFloat(price.replace("R$", "").replace(",",".").replace(" ", "")).toFixed(2);

});
```

It's not a great way to go about it though, it's probably best to put the initial price as an attribute of the input and use `attr()` to get it.

```
<input type="number" id="item1" name="item1" step="1" min="0" max="10" data-price="2.50"/>

$('input#item1').keypress(function() {
     const price = $(this).attr('data-price');
});
```

Comment: Good idea, but i think it is better to use `$(this).data("price")` to retrive data attr value.

Comment: @GiacomoPenuti `.data("price")` will not return the value as it's rendered on the dom. You can only retrieve values using `.data()` if they have been defined using `.data()`

Comment: Sorry but i have to say, according to JQuery docs, that `.data(key)` function description is "Return the value at the named data store for the first element in the jQuery collection, as set by data(name, value) _or by an HTML5 data-* attribute_" (https://api.jquery.com/data/).
According to this, i prefer to use data function to retrive data- attributes (https://jsfiddle.net/a7orj9c3/3/).

Comment: @GiacomoPenuti My bad, I just use data attribute in that way as it's not fulproof. As in if you had data-attribute-id rendered on the dom it would not find it. It doesn't like additional dashes when reading from the dom